# set UIButton's image in interface builder for differen state

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I am facing very strange issue.

In interface builder I am trying to set images for "normal" state config and for "selected" state config. but by clicking the button my image is not getting changed.

even I write the code in viewDidLoad method.

```
[btnCheckBoxMale setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blankcheckbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnCheckBoxMale setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

but my images are not getting changed on cliking on it

can anyboday say what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set selected when you call the method on button click event.. for example..

```
-(IBAction) btnCheckBoxMale_Clicked:(id)sender{
    [btnCheckBoxMale setSelected:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 28):

Set the image to different states in interface builder instead of setting it in code. Please see the screenshot for how to set it. Try this & if you are facing any problem then ask me.
[image: button image]

Answer (score 3):

It will work if you set manually in button action:

```
btnCheckBoxMale.selected = YES;
```

Because by default UIButton has only two states - Normal and Highlighted. And other states like `selected` and `disabled` you have to control manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction) btnCheckBoxMale_Clicked:(id)sender{
UIButton * btnCheckBoxMale = (UIButton *)sender;
[btnErase setSelected:! btnCheckBoxMale];
}
```